# Cut not working as a variable

Tags: linux, bash

I have a wierd situation. I am trying to cut some info from a file and everything works fine when I run the command straight into the terminal, but as soon as I make it a variable in a script it returns a mixture of what it should cut and a list of the files in the current directory.

```
cat query.sql | cut -d':' -f3,4
```

works but...

```
QUERY_SQL="query.sql"
MYSQL_COMMAND=`cat $QUERY_SQL | cut -d':' -f3,4`
echo $MYSQL_COMMAND
```

returns the wierd output mentioned above.
What am I doing wrong?

EDIT:
The query file looks something like this...

```
email@somehwhere.com:3:SQL CODE
```

Comment: Does `echo $QUERY_SQL` do what it should?

Comment: yes it does..only thing that changes is that they are now variables

Comment: @anubhava same output

Comment: The only change I got when trying, is that running the command directly will output a multi line result, while `echo`ing the result will print everything on the same line.

Comment: @Xaqq are you using the above sql file format and do you have some other files in your working directory?

Comment: put `set -x` at top of your script and then use quotes for assignment: `MYSQL_COMMAND='$(cut -d ":" -f3,4 "$QUERY_SQL")'`

Comment: @user1991424 I copy-pasted your example, and tried it in /tmp, so yes and yes.

Comment: Also make sure to echo output with quotes: `echo "$MYSQL_COMMAND"`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect something in the contents of `MYSQL_COMMAND` is being interpreted as a filename glob pattern.  Try changing

```
MYSQL_COMMAND=`cat $QUERY_SQL | cut -d':' -f3,4`
echo $MYSQL_COMMAND
```

to

```
MYSQL_COMMAND="$(cut -d: -f3,4 < "$QUERY_SQL")"
printf '%s\n' "$MYSQL_COMMAND"
```

Best defensive coding practice for shell is to put double quotes around *every* variable substitution, unless you *know for a fact* that you need word splitting and glob expansion to happen after a particular substitution.  Changing `echo` to `printf '%s\n'` avoids a related set of problems.  I can never remember whether you actually need double quotes around `$(...)` in a variable assignment, so I put them in just to be safe.

Comment: That works...thank you for the advice, you just helped me get a little better at shell scripting!

Comment: By the way it worked without the double quotes around `$(cut -d: -f3,4 < "$QUERY_SQL")`